# Intent to another activity on click searchview result

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have search various of ways, but I can't seem to understand on how to get this thing work.

I just want, whenever `textview` in the `expandablelistview` is clicked to go into another `activity`. But, I want to specify the onclicks of user to their own activities. How can i do that?

To cut the long story short, All I want to know is how do I handle the `onclick` of my `textview`?

This is code where I should be putting my intent in:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ChildRow childRow = (ChildRow) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
    }

    ImageView childIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_icon);
    childIcon.setImageResource(childRow.getIcon());

    final TextView childText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_text);
    childText.setText(childRow.getText().trim());

    final View finalConvertView = convertView;
    childText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Codes for intent goes in here.
            Toast.makeText(finalConvertView.getContext()
                    , childText.getText()
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

A help is pretty much needed and appreciated, please mind helping me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say you are using an `arraylist` of items. you can access the list items using the `childposition`. all you need to do is pass that element using an intent 
take a look at the following code.

```
  private List<ItemDetail> itemList = new ArrayList<ItemDetail>();


    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
        }


         final TextView childText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_text);
         childText.setText(itemList.get(childPosition));


        final View finalConvertView = convertView;
        childText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Codes for intent goes in here.
           Intent intent = new Intent(this,YourActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("datakey", itemList.get(childPosition));
           startActivity(intent);
         }
        });

       return convertView;

    }
```

Comment: Should I pass the data into the Activity where the mainactivity of my expandablelist adapter?

Comment: passing the data is not necessary , you said all you want is to be specific about the click , you can pass the `child position` from the `intent` as well then use that to access the `element` from the list.

Answer (score 1):

The code below must be inside of an `Activity` class. You first must create an intent to the particular activity you would like to go to. The call to `putExtra()` is optional; you can use it to pass data to the new activity. Then, you need to call `startActivity()` and pass it the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(NewActivity.DATA_KEY, data);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Yes, I can see your point. But, what I'm having a problem at is, how to I determine what data in the result of my searchview was click, how do I suppose to know and create an intent for each of it?